# Deep Linking in Nested Navigators in react navigation

Tags: react-native

I am using react-navigation and as per the structure of my application, we have a tab navigator inside stack navigator, I am not been able to find any proper guide for implementing Deep-Linking.

> https://v1.reactnavigation.org/docs/deep-linking.html. this doesn't give any reference for nested navigators.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So, after the arrival of V3 of react navigation,** things got extremely stable. Now i will present you a navigation structure with deep-linking in a Switch navigator -> drawerNavigator-> tabNavigator -> stack-> navigator. Please go step by step and understand the structure and keep referring to official documentation at everystep

**With nested navigators people generally mean navigation structure which consists of drawer navigator, tab navigator and stackNavigator. In V3 we have SwitchNavigator too. So let's just get to the code,**

```
//here we will have the basic React and react native imports which depends on what you want to render
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
    Platform,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View, Animated, Easing, Image,
    Button,
    TouchableOpacity, TextInput, SafeAreaView, FlatList, Vibration, ActivityIndicator, PermissionsAndroid, Linking
} from "react-native";
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer, createDrawerNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator, createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation";

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true
        }
    }
    render() {
        return <AppContainer uriPrefix={prefix} />;
    }
}
class WelcomeScreen extends Component {
    state = {
        fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0.2),  // Initial value for opacity: 0
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        Animated.timing(                  // Animate over time
            this.state.fadeAnim,            // The animated value to drive
            {
                toValue: 1,
                easing: Easing.back(),                  // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
                duration: 1000,
                useNativeDriver: true           // Make it take a while
            }
        ).start();                        // Starts the animation
    }

    render() {
        let { fadeAnim } = this.state;
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center", backgroundColor: '#000' }}>
                <Animated.View                 // Special animatable View
                    style={{ opacity: fadeAnim }}
                >
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Dashboard")}
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor: "orange",
                            alignItems: "center",
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            height: 30,
                            width: 100,
                            borderRadius: 10,
                            borderColor: "#ccc",
                            borderWidth: 2,
                            marginBottom: 10
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text>Login</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </Animated.View>
                <Animated.View                 // Special animatable View
                    style={{ opacity: fadeAnim }}
                >
                    <TouchableOpacity
                        onPress={() => alert("buttonPressed")}
                        style={{
                            backgroundColor: "orange",
                            alignItems: "center",
                            justifyContent: "center",
                            height: 30,
                            width: 100,
                            borderRadius: 10,
                            borderColor: "#ccc",
                            borderWidth: 2
                        }}
                    >
                        <Text> Sign Up</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </Animated.View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
class Feed extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
                <Button
                    onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("DetailsScreen")}
                    title="Go to details"
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
class Profile extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, }}>
            //Somecode
            </SafeAreaView>
        );
    }
}
class Settings extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            //Some code
            </View>
        );
    }
}
const feedStack = createStackNavigator({
    Feed: {
        screen: Feed,
        path: 'feed',
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            return {
                headerTitle: "Feed",
                headerLeft: (
                    <Icon
                        style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
                        name="md-menu"
                        size={30}
                        onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
                    />
                )
            };
        }
    },
    DetailsScreen: {
        screen: Detail,
        path: 'details',
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            return {
                headerTitle: "Details",
            };
        }
    }
});
const profileStack = createStackNavigator({
    Profile: {
        screen: Profile,
        path: 'profile',
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            return {
                headerTitle: "Profile",
                headerMode: 'Float',
                headerLeft: (
                    <Icon
                        style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
                        name="md-menu"
                        size={30}
                        onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
                    />
                )
            };
        }
    },
    DetailsScreen: {
        screen: Detail,
        path: 'details',
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            return {
                headerTitle: "Details"
            };
        }
    }
});
const settingStack = createStackNavigator({
    Settings: {
        screen: Settings,
        path: 'settings',
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            return {
                headerTitle: "Settings",
                headerLeft: (
                    <Icon
                        style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
                        name="md-menu"
                        size={30}
                        onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
                    />
                )
            };
        }
    },
    DetailsScreen: {
        screen: Detail,
        path: 'details',
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            return {
                headerTitle: "Details"
            };
        },

    }
});
const DashboardTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(
    {
        feedStack: {
            screen: feedStack,
            path: 'feedStack',
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
                let tabBarVisible = true;
                if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
                    tabBarVisible = false;
                }
                return {
                    tabBarLabel: "Feed",
                    tabBarVisible,
                    //iconName :`ios-list${focused ? '' : '-outline'}`,
                    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                        <Icon name="ios-list" color={tintColor} size={25} />
                    )
                };
            }
        },

        profileStack: {
            screen: profileStack,
            path: 'profileStack',
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation, focused }) => {
                let tabBarVisible = true;
                if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
                    tabBarVisible = false
                }
                return {
                    tabBarVisible,
                    tabBarLabel: "Profile",
                    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                        <Icon name="ios-man" color={tintColor} size={25} />
                    )
                };
                // focused:true,
            }
        },
        settingStack: {
            screen: settingStack,
            path: 'settingsStack',
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
                let tabBarVisible = true;
                if (navigation.state.index > 0) {
                    tabBarVisible = false;
                }
                return {
                    tabBarVisible,
                    tabBarLabel: "Settings",
                    tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor }) => (
                        <Icon name="ios-options" color={tintColor} size={25} />
                    )
                }

            }
        },

    },
    {
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {

            const { routeName } = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
            return {
                // headerTitle: routeName,

                header: null
            };
        },
        tabBarOptions: {
            //showLabel: true, // hide labels
            activeTintColor: "orange", // active icon color
            inactiveTintColor: "#586589" // inactive icon color
            //activeBackgroundColor:'#32a1fe',
        }
    }
);
const DashboardStackNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
        DashboardTabNavigator: {
            screen: DashboardTabNavigator,
            path: 'dashboardtabs'
        },
        DetailsScreen: {
            screen: Detail,
            path: 'details',
            navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
                return {
                    headerTitle: "Details"
                };
            }
        }
    },
    {
        defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            return {
                headerLeft: (
                    <Icon
                        style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
                        name="md-menu"
                        size={30}
                        onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
                    />
                )
            };
        }
    }
);
const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
    Dashboard: {
        screen: DashboardStackNavigator,
        path: 'welcome'
    },
    DetailsScreen: {
        screen: Detail,
        path: 'friends',
        navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
            return {
                headerTitle: "Details",

            };
        }
    }
});
//Switch navigator , will be first to load
const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
    Welcome: {
        screen: WelcomeScreen,

    },
    Dashboard: {
        screen: AppDrawerNavigator,
        path: 'welcome'
    }
});
const prefix = 'myapp://';
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);
```

> For the process to setup React-navigation deep-linking please follow the [official documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/deep-linking.html)
>
> DetailsScreen was in my different folder and that will have class component of your choice
>
> To launch the App the deep-link URL is **myapp://welcome**
>
> To go to root page the deep-link URL is **myapp://welcome/welcome**
>   (this will reach at first page of first tab of tab navigator)
>
> To go to any particular screen of tab navigator (suppose details
>   screen in profile tab) -
>   **myapp://welcome/welcome/profileStack/details**

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You have to basically pass a `path` to every upper route untill you come to you nested route. This is indipendent of the type of navigator you use.

```
const HomeStack = createStackNavigator({
    Article: {
        screen: ArticleScreen,
        path: 'article',
    },
});

const SimpleApp = createAppContainer(createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: { 
        screen: HomeStack,
        path: 'home',
    },
}));

const prefix = Platform.OS == 'android' ? 'myapp://myapp/' : 'myapp://';

const MainApp = () => <SimpleApp uriPrefix={prefix} />;
```

In this case to route to an inner Navigator this is the route: `myapp://home/article`.

This example is using `react-navigation@^3.0.0`, but is easy to transfer to `v1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    const config = {
  Tabs: {
    screens: {
      UserProfile: {
        path: 'share//user_share/:userId',
        parse: {
          userId: (userId) => `${userId}`,
        },
      },
    },
  },
};

const linking = {
  prefixes: ['recreative://'],
  config,
};
```

if you have a screen in tab navigator you can do it like this via react-navigation v5